# pandas python get table with the first date of event in every year, each country, alternative groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Who can help, I'm trying to group this table here ( [original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG1qG.jpg) ) with tables : (country, year, date of the earthquake) in this form: the first earthquake in every year, each country. I was able to group through groupby, ( [table with groupby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7ecY.jpg) ), but this view does not suit me, I need the same result  but in this view :

```
China                  2002            06-28
China                  2005            07-25
China                  2009            05-10
China                  2010            03-10
China                  2011            05-10
... ... ... ...
the Kuril Islands      2017            04-07
the Kuril Islands      2018            01-06

the Volcano Islands    2010            10-24
the Volcano Islands    2013            08-24
the Volcano Islands    2015            04-02
```

06-28 = month-day

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get your `groupby` use `df = df.reset_index()`.
This will bring the columns you used in the groupby to columns and will get you the result you want